# WILDFLY - JAAS doesn´t work - SecurityDomain not recognised

Tags: java, jaas, wildfly

I´m trying do set a security Domain in wildfly but is not recognizing my settings and it's go to a protected page without passing to a login page.

---

```
TABLES:
'groups' table,
 @Column(name = "groupname")
    private String groupname;

'applicant' table,
    @Id
    private Integer id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;


'groupshasapplicant' table,
    @Id
    private Integer id;
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;
    @Column(name = "groupname")
    private String groupname;
```

---

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Production</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/offersList.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>applicant</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>applicant</web-resource-name>
            <description/>
            <url-pattern>/faces/registed/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>    
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <description/>
            <role-name>Applicant</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <description/>
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <realm-name>jBossJaasMysqlRealmApp</realm-name>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/faces/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/faces/error.xhtml</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>
    <security-role>
        <description/>
        <role-name>Applicant</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <error-page>
        <!-- Missing login -->
        <error-code>401</error-code>
        <location>/faces/error.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <!-- Forbidden directory listing -->
        <error-code>403</error-code>
        <location>/faces/template.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <!-- Uncaught exception -->
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/faces/error.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <!-- Unsupported servlet method -->
        <error-code>503</error-code>
        <location>/faces/error.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <!-- Not found -->
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/faces/error.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>
</web-app>
```

---

jboss-web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee">
  <security-domain>jBossJaasMysqlRealmApp</security-domain>
  <context-root>/publicPositionPlataform</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

---

Into WILDFLY configurations I have the standalone-full like this:

```
<security-domain name="jBossJaasMysqlRealmApp">
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module code="Database" flag="required">
                            <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:jboss/datasources/positionsdb"/>
                            <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="select password from applicant where username = ?"/>
                            <module-option name="rolesName" value="select groupname, 'Roles' from grouphasapplicant where groupname = ?"/>
                            <module-option name="hashAlgorithm" value="SHA-256"/>
                            <module-option name="hashEncoding" value="hex"/>
                            <module-option name="unauthenticatedIdentity" value="guest"/>
                        </login-module>
                        <login-module code="RoleMapping" flag="required">
                            <module-option name="rolesProperties" value="file:${jboss.server.config.dir}/app.properties"/>
                            <module-option name="replaceRole" value="false"/>
                        </login-module>
                    </authentication>
                </security-domain>
```

---

Comment: share your data source, web.xml and login.xhtml files to get clearity...

Answer (score 0):

Try java:/jaas/jBossJaasMysqlRealmApp in your jboss-web.xml.